# How to receive an iterator of strings on STL algorithm

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I need to develop an algorithm for a library that receives a "list of strings".

Of course I want to pass an "abstract" iterator to decouple the internal representation of that list (a vector, a linked list, a map...) to the access to it from my function.

This is my approach:

```
template <typename ForwardIterator>
void myAlgorithm(ForwardIterator itBegin, ForwardIterator itEnd) {
   for(; itBegin != itEnd ; ++itBegin) {
       // Do something with *itBegin
   }
}
```

My question is, how can I restrict the type of the container to be string? Or even more, is there some way of accepting both std::strings and char* as elements?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The first question does it make sense restricting it? Template use what is called duck typing so as long it behaves like a string it will work. So just use a string method inside `myAlgorithm` and it will only work with types with that method.

Comment: What Martin said.  There is a problem with C++'s template 'duck typing' and that's when someone tries to use your template with a type that won't work, the error message is often quite cryptic. Compilers are getting better with these error messages, but it is still a problem.

Comment: Why does it have to be a sequence of strings? Wouldn't your algorithm work with other elements in the sequence? What about a sequence of `vector`s of `char`s? And what about `my_sequential_container<char>`? Or a sequence of `my_string`? How about wide strings? ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a static assertion along with `std::iterator_traits<>`:

```
template<typename ForwardIterator>
void myAlgorithm(ForwardIterator itBegin, ForwardIterator itEnd) {
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::value_type value_t;
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((
        boost::is_same<value_t, std::string>::value ||
        boost::is_same<value_t, char const*>::value
    ));

    for(; itBegin != itEnd ; ++itBegin) {
        // Do something with *itBegin
    }
}
```

If you're using a C++0x compiler, you can use `static_assert` instead of [`BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/static_assert/static_assert.htm) and `std::is_same` instead of [`boost::is_same`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_same.html).

Comment: What if I try to use this algorithm with s `std::vector<char*>`?

Comment: @sbi : I see what you're getting at, but again, I don't have time to think up and post an ideal solution at the moment. If someone else does, I'd happily vote it up. :-] EDIT: I don't see how Fred's answer would work any better or worse for `vector<char*>`.

Comment: @ildjarn: My point is that we should question the requirement, rather than giving superficial solutions.

Comment: @sbi : I question requirements when I have time to do so -- when I don't, I simply give the person asking the question the benefit of the doubt that _they've_ thought their requirements through.

Comment: @ildjarn: Of course, I also only question the requirements if I have the time to do so. However, if I don't have it, (1) I either don't answer or I will have to live with others pointing out the flaws, and (2) I understand that I'm implausible I when spend a lot of time explaining that I have none to spare. `:)`

Comment: Perhaps `std::is_convertible` would be appropriate to future-proof the requirements (Boost also has it).

Comment: @sbi : Well I guess right now I'm living with others pointing out the flaws. ;-]

Comment: See the last sentence of my answer, then it also works with `vector<char*>` and `vector<const char*>`.

Comment: @FredOverflow : He means the iterator's value_type is `vector<char*>`, not passing in a `vector<char*>::iterator`. `is_convertible<vector<char*>, string>::value` is `false`.

Comment: @sbi: Is that what you meant?

Comment: @FredOverflow : It's explicitly what he said on his comment on the question -- "*What about a sequence of `vector`s of `char`s?*"

Comment: Okay, but I don't think @McK actually *wants* his algorithm to work with nested containers. It seems to me that he only wants to process containers of strings and containers of character pointers. Correct my if I'm wrong.

Comment: @FredOverflow : I just realized that in my previous comments I kept saying `vector<char*>` where I meant `vector<char>` (damn this 5 minute edit restriction ;-[ ). I believe sbi's (valid) point is that semantically, a sequence of `vector<char>`s shouldn't be any different than a sequence of `std::string`s or a sequence of `char*`s. The code you and I have presented would not work with a sequence of `vector<char>`s.

Comment: @Fred: In my comment to the question I was questioning the approach. In my comment too @ildjarn I was pointing out that that is what we ought to do here. `:)` Of course, the OP might have perfectly fine reason to limit the algorithm to _any_ sequences of _only_ `std::string` objects. But IMO the first thing to do would still be to question that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::enable_if` to restrict the possible template arguments:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iterator>

template <typename ForwardIterator>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<
        typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::value_type,
        std::string
    >::value, void
>::type
myAlgorithm(ForwardIterator itBegin, ForwardIterator itEnd) {
   for(; itBegin != itEnd ; ++itBegin) {
       // Do something with *itBegin
   }
}
```

Although I don't really see the point in this restriction.

> Is there some way of accepting both std::strings and char* as elements?

Sure, just replace `std::is_same` with `std::is_convertible`.